# Split sentences in table

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I have a table with two columns: a word and its description, which is a sentences. Now, when I create a pdf, the sentences run out of the page boundary. Is it possible to automatically split the sentences in Latex or do linebreaks need to be used?

Comment: Use `\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\linewidth}m{0.2\linewidth}}`.

Comment: With 2 times 'p', thus {p{0.5\linewidth}p{0.2\linewidth}} it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a `p{<length>}` column in the tabular format (`p{<length>}` behaves like `\parbox[t]{width}` and text will wrap); if you load the `array` package you can also use `m{<length>}` which is similar but now every entry will be centered in proportion to the rest of the line. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate some text

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{lp{8cm}}
Left aligned column & \lipsum[1]
\end{tabular}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{lm{8cm}}
Left aligned column & \lipsum[1]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]